# Liferay auto assign users to an organization on register

Tags: liferay, organization

How do I auto-assign a user to an organization when they register to a liferay portal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can automatically assign new users to sites, roles and user groups, but not organizations.
Anyway, there are surely many ways to achieve what you want with just a few lines of code.

For example, you can develop a hook plugin which overrides the `addUserWithWorkflow` method of the `UserLocalService` service, so you can add a new organization ID to the `organizationIds` parameter before calling `super.addUserWithWorkflow(...)`.

Hope it helps!